# Accounting value of Splay trees?

Tags: data-structures, correctness-proof, splay-trees

In Splay trees, by definition - the required element x - rises to the root of the tree, using the operations: zig, zig-zig, zig-zag. And the formula zig of the step is this: `1 + 3 (r '(v) -r (v))`, where - `r' (v) -r (v)` is the length of the path before the path x is raised to the vertex, and the coefficient 1 is " actual payment for actions "

But here is the question: where does the coefficient 3 come from?

The zig-zig and zig-zag estimates for the step are: `3 (r '(v) -r (v))`

again the question: what does the coefficient 3 mean?

and where did it go 1 - like "actual payback for actions"? ("actual payment for actions" - in terms of accounting value)

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: Hello. Look please - is the new name suitable? Could you please put some of your options?